# swiftである変数がnilなら値を入れる方法について

Tags: swift

タイトルのことを行いたいわけですが、やり方が何パターンかあります。

もっとも単純なものは

```
//パターン1
var str:String!
if str == nil{
    str = "newValue"
}
```

次に、オプショナルバインディングを用いた時

```
//パターン2
var str:String!
if let _ = str{
    //strがnilでないとき
}else{
    //strがnilのとき
    str = "newValue"
}
```

strがnilの時だけ値をいれたいので、else句以外は不要な上、冗長です。

次に、nil結合演算子を用いた時

```
//パターン3
var str:String!
str = str ?? "newValue"
```

この場合、とても簡潔に書けるのですが、strを二回書いてるところがなんだかダサいのです。

やはりパターン１がよいのでしょうか。
何か良い方法はありますか？

Comment: これをやりたいが為に`??`が後から導入されたそうですから、パターン3が良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 「nilでないとき」に何もしないのにオプショナルバインディングを使うのはどうかと思うんですが、残りの2つについては正直どっちでもいいのではないかと思います。ちなみに手持ちのAppleのsampleコードに検索をかけてみたところ、パターン3が現れたのは20余りのうち2箇所だけでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

演算子のオーバーロードは非常にセンスが要求されるので特にオススメするわけではありませんが、カスタムオペレータを定義することでRubyの`||=`と同じようにすることもできます。

```
infix operator ||= {
    associativity right
    precedence 90
    assignment
}

func ||=<T>(inout lhs: T?, @autoclosure rhs: () -> T) {
    if(lhs == nil) {
        lhs = rhs()
    }
}

func ||=<T>(inout lhs: T!, @autoclosure rhs: () -> T) {
    if(lhs == nil) {
        lhs = rhs()
    }
}
```

http://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/06/10/implementing-rubys-operator-in-swift/